# Encoding issue: Some texts are getting converted to weird characters on placing the file on a linux server

Tags: linux, encoding, character-encoding

I have a xml file which has some dutch data in it. When I am viewing the file on my local machine (Mac OS X) in sublime text, all the characters seem to be proper.

But, when I load this file on a linux machine, some texts are getting converted to weird characters and hindering the further processing.

Here is the look of the file on my machine (with sublime text2):

[image]

and on linux machine:

[image]

this xml comes from a third party and I believe they are preparing this file on a windows machine.

I ran **locale charmap** command on both the machines and below is the output:

Mac OS: UTF-8
Linux: ISO-8859-1

I checked encoding on sublime text and its using **windows 1252**

When I view the file on terminal, it shows me special characters as well.

(output with vim command on Mac's terminal)

[image]

As per my understanding, windows 1252 encoding can't be applied on Mac and linux machines.

What can be done to fix this problem, so that I have a file with proper data on every machine?

Comment: Other than telling your text editor to read files as CP1252?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams : Sublime-text is not showing the support for CP1252 encoding. Anyway, I need to fix this on the linux machine.

Comment: The file has proper data, your terminal just cannot display it correctly. What does the <!xml> tag in the document look like and why aren't you using UTF-8 everywhere?